# ¿Por que no me logra compilar el codigo a pesar de que quiero imprimir datos a traves de listas?

Tags: c++, lista

No se por que no me logra retornar el contenido del archivo, a pesar de que se intenta traspasar.

```
void ListaDefinicion::ingreso(char palab[], char tipo[], char definicion[], int frecuencia, char ejemplo[], lista2 sinonimo[3], lista2 antonimo[3], int numAnt, int numSin) {
    palabra *q, *r;
    q = new palabra;

    if (!q) {
        cout << "No hay espacio de memoria suficiente";
    } else {
        strcpy(q->palab, palab);
        strcpy(q->tipo, tipo);
        strcpy(q->definicion, definicion);
        q->frecuencia = frecuencia;
        strcpy(q->ejemplo, ejemplo);
        q->numSin = numSin;
        q->numAnt = numAnt;

        for (int x = 0; x < numSin; x++) {
            strcpy(q->sinonimo[x].extra, sinonimo[x].extra);
            q->sinonimo[x].frec = sinonimo[x].frec;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < numAnt; x++) {
            strcpy(q->antonimo[x].extra, antonimo[x].extra);
            q->antonimo[x].frec = antonimo[x].frec;
        }

        if (!p || strcmp(q->palab, p->palab) <= 0) {
            q->sig = p;
            p = q;
        } else {
            r = p;
            while (r->sig && strcmp(q->palab, r->sig->palab) > 0) {
                r = r->sig;
            }
            q->sig = r->sig;
            r->sig = q;
        }
    }
}
```

```
void ListaDefinicion::traspaso()
{
    FILE* archivo = fopen("rae.dat", "rb");
    if (archivo == NULL) {
        cerr << "Error al abrir el archivo rae.dat" << endl;
        exit (1);
    }

    palabra O;
    while (fread(&O, sizeof(palabra), 1, archivo) == 1) {
        ingreso(O.palab, O.tipo, O.definicion, O.frecuencia, O.ejemplo, O.sinonimo, O.antonimo, O.numAnt, O.numSin);
    }

    fclose(archivo);
}
```

O puede que sea un error de traspaso del archivo para que lo pueda leer, desconozco porque igual en varios proyectos me ha logrado compilar, solamente necesito lograr imprimir por completo el contenido de un archivo a traves de estas funciones, se que puede haber un error en estas funciones ya que me retorna (0xC0000005) como error, de verdad que me gustaria saber si es que existe algun error en el codigo

O si es algun error mio en lo que corresponde, o si de lleno es un error tan infimo en la funcion de traspaso del archivo, que son mis mayores sospechas.

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver la definición del objeto `palabra` toda mi respuesta se basa en intuición; pero antes de abordar lo que creo que está pasando debo señalarte que estás confundiendo [c](/questions/tagged/c) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

1. En C++, si falla el operador `new` se lanza una excepción ([`std::bad_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)), no se devolverá un puntero nulo, así que este código no funciona como crees que funciona:

   ```
   q = new palabra;

   if (!q) {
       cout << "No hay espacio de memoria suficiente";
   }
   ```

   Debería ser así:

   ```
   try {
       q = new palabra;

       …
   }
   catch (const std::bad_alloc &e) {
       cout << "No hay espacio de memoria suficiente";
   }
   ```
2. En C++ las cadenas de texto se suelen tratar con el objeto `std::string`, no con punteros a carácter (`char *`), el objeto `std::string` automatiza la gestión de memoria, la copia de cadenas y muchas operaciones que son tediosas de hacer *manualmente*.

---

Ahora si, mi *intuición* me dice que tu objeto `palabra` tiene este aspecto:

```
struct palabra {
    char *palab;
    char *tipo;
    char *definicion;
};
```

Cuando creas una nueva instancia de `palabra` (`new palabra`), no has reservado memoria para cada uno de los punteros que tiene el objeto, así que cuando copias datos usando esos punteros:

```
strcpy(q->palab, palab);
strcpy(q->tipo, tipo);
strcpy(q->definicion, definicion);
```

Tienes un error de memoria ([Infracción de acceso a memoria `0xc0000005`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/shows/inside/c0000005)); antes de escribir usando esos punteros, tendrías que reservar memoria y asignarla a esos punteros… sin olvidar borrar la memoria al finalizar.

Olvídalo, usa `std::string`:

```
struct palabra {
    std::string palab;
    std::string tipo;
    std::string definicion;
};

void ListaDefinicion::ingreso(const std::string &palab, const std::string &tipo, const std::string &definicion, int frecuencia, const std::string &ejemplo, lista2 sinonimo[3], lista2 antonimo[3], int numAnt, int numSin) {
    palabra *q, *r;

    try {
        q = new palabra;

        q->palab = palab;
        q->tipo = tipo;
        q->definicion = definicion;

        …

    } catch (const std::bad_alloc &e) {
        cout << "No hay espacio de memoria suficiente";
    }

    …
}
```